# Error install react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Не могу установить react через npm. Вот, что выдает:

```
75 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
76 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" 
"install" "- -save" "react" "react-dom" "babel-preset-react"
77 error node v5.4.1
78 error npm  v3.3.12
79 error code ENOSELF
80 error Refusing to install react as a dependency of itself
81 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
81 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

package.json

```
{ "name": "react", "version": "1.0.0", "description": "a react app", "main": "server.js", "dependencies": {}, "devDependencies": {}, "scripts": { "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" }, "author": "bronzer", "license": "MIT" }
```

Comment: Покажите `package.json`. ...и в какой папке вы это делаете.

Comment: в той же папке где лежит проект

Comment: просто я никогда не работал с react, а тут даже npm отказывается его ставить

Comment: я удалил package и все заработало, почему так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В вашем `package.json` **ваш же проект** (модуль) называется `react`, а вы пытаетесь ему вкрутить зависимость от `react`. А сам от себя модуль зависеть не может.

Выберите ему уникальное имя (в рамках NPM). Возникшая ошибка это только одна из причин.

---

Изоляция проблемы: сделайте такой `package.json`:

```
{ "name": "react" }
```

...и сделайте в папке с ним:

```
npm install --save react
```

...получите отказ по этой же причине.

Comment: спасибо за объяснение